# String not showing up correctly when queried from a database

Tags: html, sql, .net, string

What I am trying to accomplish is very simple. I want to display the name of a schedule when its attached instance Id matched that of the instance Id being displayed in the table of my webpage. Here is the code for the table

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Instance Name</th>
        <th>Instance ID</th>
        <th>Launch Time</th>
        <th>Instance Type</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Public Ip</th>
        <th>Zone</th>
        <th>Schedule</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@{int totalcount = Model.instances.Reservations.Count;}
<tbody>
    @for (var i=0; i <= totalcount - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (var instances in Model.instances.Reservations[i].Instances)
        {
        <tr>
            @* if an instance gets terminated and has no name it will show up as blank and stop the describe call from breaking *@
            @if (instances.Tags.Count > 0)
            {
            <td>
                @instances.Tags[0].Value
            </td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No Name</td>
            }
            <td>@instances.InstanceId</td>
            <td>@instances.LaunchTime</td>
            <td>@instances.InstanceType</td>
            <td>@instances.State.Name</td>f
            <td>@instances.PublicIpAddress</td>
            <td>@instances.Placement.AvailabilityZone</td>
            @foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
            {
                if(instances.InstanceId == row.ServerId)
                {
                    <td>row.ScheduleName</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>Unscheduled</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

the query string is declared above like so.

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM ScheduledServer ORDER BY Id";
}
```

When running the query in ssms I get the following result [image]

But when I take a look at the value of `row.ServerId` instead of the string being i-a137e32b its displayed as \ti-a137e32b so it skips the if condition and does not display the schedule name. I am not very well versed in Razor or SQL so I have no idea why the \t is being appended onto the start of my string.

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing the `\t` as a result of copying from the results pane of the query.  If you try `SELECT Id, '*' + ServerId + '*', ScheduleName FROM ScheduledServer ORDER BY Id` do you still see the tab immediately before the actual `ServerId`?

Comment: The format of your query threw an error "Additional information: Invalid column name 'ServerId'" I am using MSSQL if that makes any difference.

Comment: If `ServerId` is an invalid column then what SQL generated the result set shown in your screenshot?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
          ,[ServerId]
          ,[ScheduleName]
      FROM [EC2ManagementTool].[dbo].[ScheduledServer]

Comment: So when you run `SELECT TOP 1000 [Id] ,'*' + [ServerId] + '*',[ScheduleName] FROM [EC2ManagementTool].[dbo].[ScheduledServer]` do you have a tab character after the asterisk and before the `ServerId` value?

Comment: When executing it in ssms I don't but changing the query variable to that in the razor page throws the same invalid ServerId error

Comment: That's good because you've eliminated the idea that the tab character is part of the problem.  I would suggest looking/printing the values in the web page of `instances.InstanceId` and `row.ServerId` so you can be see whether they are actually what you think they are.

Comment: Sorry I am slightly confused. When stepping into the code the values were what I posted in the above questions. `instances.InstanceId` is pulled from  an amazon ec2 instance and will always equal  i-a137e32b and in the database the ServerId for that row should also equal that as the SELECT query showed that it should not have /t appended to the start of it.

Comment: I see the problem thanks for your input it helped greatly

Comment: If you think your solution might be helpful for other people, consider posting it as your own answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /t was being appended to the start of the string because it was in the string. MSSQL shows /t as a single whitespace character in the ssms results pane therefore I kept glancing over it until I started submitting more data entries. Infact if you look at the image in the question you can slightly see it pushed to the right.